# Build a dedicated Search Server on Azure VM with Solr

Tags: azure, solr, lucene

I am a .NET guy with no knowledge about Linux, Apache, Java and Solr. But after research, I still think build a dedicated search server is the way to go.

What I want to achieve is: build a dedicated search server based on Solr and host on Azure Virtual Machine. I will use REST api to update the index and query. So for the server itself is set and forget (I hope).

Here is the plan after research, please advice.

Question 1: Get a Azure Virtual Machine, install Solr as [this article advised](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/Azure/Getting_Started_Guide_Solr_Lucene.asp). then where the persistent storage place (to put indexes), how to make sure it will not gone after the server reboot or redeploy.

Question 2: I want only my another instance in Azure can query, so is the Virtual Network come to play?

Question 3: Is this setup really maintenance free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Question 1: The data will be persisted using a Cloud Drive (a page blob in Blob Storage) and this is persisted after a server reboot or redeploy.
- Question 2: If you add more roles to that same hosted service/cloud service you don't even need to bother with a Virtual Network, you can simply use internal endpoints. If you're trying to access the hosted service/cloud service that hosts Solr from a different hosted service/cloud service or virtual machine, then you'll need to use a Virtual Network.
- Question 3: I'm not convinced that this setup is really maintenance free. Think of auto scaling your slaves, ... Did you ever consider [LucidWorks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/06/11/solr-and-lucidworks-enterprise-search-for-windows-azure.aspx) (which is a Windows Azure partner for Solr)?

Comment: I checked "LucidWorks", too expensive. Because I am search items in small size, normally 5k each, and I have 10 million of them :( I saw all these services are charged by "documents" not by index size, so I have to build my own, and I will put indexer/searcher/etc all in one VM for start.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution: Use the VM depot to deploy Solr in a matter of minutes

[image]

More info: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/browse-and-use-images-from-the-vm-depot/

Comment: @SandrindoDiMattia Looks like they removed that image.  Don't see it in the list anymore.